# Copying a repository with tortoise hg : Access denied 255

Tags: clone, tortoisehg

I am trying to clone a repo with `TortoiseHg Version 2.4.2` including `Mercurial-2.2.3`, `Python-2.7.3`, `PyQt-4.9.1`, `Qt-4.8.0`.

This is the Hg command:  `hg clone --verbose --directory adress -- my repo`

It´s the same command other users are using but I always get a

```
remote: abort: Permission denied: .../.hg/store/00changelog.i
abort: unexpected response: empty string
command returned code 255;
```

Could it be possible that there is something with an IP range for the access of the files? Or the user access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn´t work was that my account was not set up as trusted user.

Adding the account to the trusted user and group and then it worked smooth.